# Perl subtitute not working after previous pattern match

Tags: perl

I have a strange problem that the susbtitute operator `s///` doesn't work after a preceding pattern match. For example

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $var = "var"; 
$var =~ s||/|g; 

print "$var\n";
```

The output is: `/v/a/r/`

But in this case

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $a = "test"; 

if ($a =~ /te/) { 

    my $var = "var"; 
    $var =~ s||/|g; 

    print "$var\n"; 
}
```

the output is: `var`, when it should be the same as the previous result.

What is going on here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) has this to say about the ***The empty pattern //***

> If the PATTERN evaluates to the empty string, the last *successfully* matched regular expression is used instead. In this case, only the g and c flags on the empty pattern are honored; the other flags are taken from the original pattern. If no match has previously succeeded, this will (silently) act instead as a genuine empty pattern (which will always match).

So your first case does a substitution on the empty string because there have been no previous pattern matches, while the second comes after a successful match of `te` in `test`, so it substitutes `te` everywhere in `var` and so has no effect.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'a/b/c';

if ($str =~ m{/}) {
  $str =~ s//x/g;
}

print $str;
```

**output**

```
axbxc
```

The only exception to this is the pattern in the `split` command, which always matches an empty pattern if that is what you specify.

To get around this, if you *really* want to match the point before and after every character, you can use the `/x` modifier to use an insignificant space for your pattern, like this

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $var_a = 'test'; 

if ($var_a =~ /te/) { 

    my $var_b = 'var'; 
    $var_b =~ s| |/|gx; 

    print "$var_b\n"; 
}
```

**output**

```
/v/a/r/
```

Comment: Many thanks, i got it :-) (that problem was blowing my mind :D, and thanks for the edit too).